# Cloud service web role trace statements are not writing to file but writing to logs table

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

Cloud service web role trace statements are not writing to file but writing to logs table,I read through the many blogs and configured all config files but still  am not able to find why these trace statements are not writing to file as well as container also not created.  I checked the connection string which is correct. Please suggest if any one has IDEA on this.  really struck up here also please suggest is there any other logging framework can be used in cloud service web role c#. My requirement is to capture all trace statements in a log file and update these statements in a blob. and this blob should be taken backup on next day and another log file should be generated in the blob

Answer (score 1):

Trace logs are always written to `WADLogsTable` table in your diagnostics storage account. If your requirement is to persist them in blob storage, there are two things you could do:

1. Let them persist in table storage and then every day read data from this table, create a CSV file of that data, and save it in blob storage. Once the blob is saved, you can delete the entries from table.
2. Implement your own trace logs collection logic using something like NLog and have it persist in blob storage. Azure CAT team has an excellent project where they make use of NLog to collect and persist diagnostics data in blob storage. You can read more about this project here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18146.windows-azure-telemetry-basics-and-troubleshooting.aspx.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I did not find where they are storing in the blob stuff. could you please point me the exact way of doing, I am really struck up here.

Comment: Are you looking for details on #1 or #2 I mentioned above?

Comment: I need details for #2. Please suggest. I need to achive a functionality like capture all trace statements and write to a log file and post the log file to azure container as a blob. The blob should rollover on daily basis.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, but the link which you provided says "page does not exist". Can you check the link once again, or if possible please post the code.

Comment: Try this link: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Cloud-Service-Fundamentals-4ca72649.

Comment: This link also says page does not exist.